# Disable AppCenter dock reminder

Tags: updates, notifications, appcenter

From time to time, AppCenter will find an update and hang out in my dock with a red, circular "badge" overlay and a number.

[image: icon]

- How can I deactivate this persistent dock notification?
- Separately, how do I stop AppCenter from automatically checking on updates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The AppCenter periodically shows updates because it runs in the background on startup. To disable its notifications, set it to not run on startup:

1. **`mkdir ~/.config/autostart/`**
2. **`cp /etc/xdg/autostart/io.elementary.appcenter-daemon.desktop ~/.config/autostart/`**

   This copies the AppCenter startup directions from the general autostart folder to your personal folder. (The startup process [prioritizes](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html#idm140434866702736) directions given in the latter.) Then modify the new file to not load on startup:
3. **`echo "X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false" | tee -a ~/.config/autostart/io.elementary.appcenter-daemon.desktop`**
4. **`reboot`**

---

If you would like to keep AppCenter running but just remove the badge, there is currently [no configuration setting](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eelementary-apps/appcenter/appcenter/view/head:/schemas/org.pantheon.appcenter.gschema.xml) for this. (Badge counts are [hardcoded](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/123/5565) in their other instances.) If you'd like to build your own version without notifications, start with modifying [`/src/Core/Client.vala`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eelementary-apps/appcenter/appcenter/view/head:/src/Core/Client.vala) and [`/src/Widgets/AppCellRenderer.vala`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eelementary-apps/appcenter/appcenter/view/head:/src/Widgets/AppCellRenderer.vala) in the source code.

Answer (score 8):

To the first question, you can open a terminal and type:

```
killall appcenter
```

Now the reminder dessapears from Planck.

To the second question, you can try to show all the hidden startup applications. Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo sed -i 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
```

Then launch the Gnome session properties from terminal:

```
gnome-session-properties
```

Look for the appcenter launcher and uncheck it. It called:

```
appcenter -s
```

Source of some parts of this answer by [@cipricus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/32012/cipricus):

[How to access and edit Startup applications in Elementary OS Freya beta 2?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/184751/194322)

Comment: I didn't realize that it was running in the background so thanks for that. But that `sed` command is destructive to all items in `*.desktop` as written

Comment: Thank you bitseater, it worked like a charm. @wolf, it is not, it just unhides the autostarted apps that elementary doesn't want you to see for cosmetic reasons.

Comment: For elementary OS 5.0 Juno the first command should be `killall io.elementary.appcenter`

Answer (score 2):

`killall io.elementary.appcenter` worked for me
to kill the process