# How to disable auto-update in Loki

Tags: release-loki, appcenter

The new AppCenter appears to periodically and automatically update the `apt` indexes which is not a problem, however, [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/appcenter/+bug/1587975) means that every time it does so, `packagekitd` hogs CPU until I purposefully kill it.

Is there any way that I can disable the auto-update feature in AppCenter or the otherwise responsible application whilst the bug is attended to?

Comment: You can check if this answer can help you: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/8640/6398 by @bitseater

Comment: Thanks - it would be great, however, to keep AppCenter whilst preventing it from updating all the time

Comment: I understand from the second aswer of @bitseater that appcenter is preserved. It only prevents updating.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable AppCenter dock reminder](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8629/disable-appcenter-dock-reminder)

Answer (score 1):

Using your favorite editor open the file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic and change:

`APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";`
to
`APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";`

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure if this will work, but have you tried editing `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` to disable the auto update of the package list?

I went the other way and actually have my server upgrade over night (except the kernel, so no reboots) but that may not be what you want.