# How to stop AppCenter New Updates?

Tags: updates, appcenter

I'm not a linux expert. And I'm afraid to have problems about Wireless, wired or sound issue because of a system update.

So, I wonder how to stop `AppCenter` update notifications?

Comment: I strongly believe Computer system ( elementary os )needs to be up to date to avoid bugs and security issues. so I would recommend to update it as often as necessary.

Comment: Do you think something like this: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8629/disable-appcenter-dock-reminder ?

Comment: Yes I had applied this solution to startup. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've overcome this issue by adding a custom command to the startup:

System Settings -> Applications -> Startup -> 'plus sign' -> `killall appcenter`

And it lives still. I just put it to sleep (silence). With this way `AppCenter` works only if I open it on Applications menu!

Comment: I tried to apply this to Juno, that is System Settings -> Applications -> Startup -> 'plus sign' -> io.elementary.appcenter But the question is: is that possible that there is no place where to unset automatic update notifications? Best
Pietro

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of it completely by issuig:

`sudo apt remove appcenter`

Answer (score 0):

The *reason* AppCenter is auto-starting when you log in is `/etc/xdg/autostart/io.elementary.appcenter-daemon.desktop`. I guess you could theoretically remove this (as root), except it'd probably be replaced after an update and you'd be back to where you started.

If you remove AppCenter entirely, which is probably inadvisable, you may want to look into the [`unattended-upgrades` package](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades) as an alternative.

That package adds configuration files to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` which, in principle, apply important security updates automatically and without user intervention… which, in principle, I would prefer to AppCenter incessantly nagging me about them. *Most* updates are unnecessary if your software is already working the way you like it, but *security* updates are an exception. My attitude is sure, operating system, do your security stuff without asking me, just don't update any apps that change the whole user interface or whatever.

Lastly, keep in mind that AppCenter's update features are basically a graphical interface on top of `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` followed by `flatpak update`. Just running those commands in a terminal is sometimes a better experience than waiting for AppCenter to struggle through a bunch of updates, especially if your wifi is spotty.