# AppCenter keeps poping up in dock

Tags: release-hera, updates, appcenter, plank, notifications

I disabled any kind of notifications for AppCenter and removed it from the dock, but nevertheless once there is software update available it appears again. Why? How can I disable that behavior?

**Background**. I have set up [automatic updates](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades) without my intervention, because I don't want to go through update process every time I start my PC. While I understand that security is in the first place and system has to be updated regularly I find that behavior very annoying and distracting.

Maybe there is possibility to stop AppCenter background task?

Comment: In /etc/xdg/autostart/ there's a file `io.elementary.appcenter-daemon.desktop` that you can delete or rename to prevent AppCenter daemon from starting with the system. Unfortunately, each update recreates that file so you'd have to delete it after each update.
I never liked an AppCenter from any distro so maybe remove it from the system altogether.

Comment: Thanks. Actually found this post that was very helpful. https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8629/disable-appcenter-dock-reminder?rq=1