# How to get badge notifications on the dock icon for third-party apps?

Tags: release-juno, plank, notifications, notification-badge

In my case it's Caprine (Facebook messenger app). In `caprine.desktop` I added `X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true` and `Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;Chat;`, but I only get notifications in the notification center and bubble notifications, without a red badge like there is one in Mail or AppCenter. 
This might be an answer, but I'm not sure if it still applies to Juno: [How do I enable notification badges on plank?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/123/how-do-i-enable-notification-badges-on-plank)

Comment: It mind sound funny and irrelevant, I was also looking into this. I could have offered a bounty on this if you didn't!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you've linked to the right answer: Plank's badges are separate from notification center, and they have to be implemented separately. However, you might consider adding a wishlist item on the [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/plank).

Comment: Pretty sure is not good enough for +100 reputation.

Comment: I'm fully aware.